# Broken CPUID brand string?

Tags: c++, assembly, x86-64, masm, uefi

I am printing some information about CPU in my OS using CPUID instruction.

Reading and printing vendor string(GenuineIntel) works well, but reading brand string gives me little strange string.

```
ok cpu-info <= Run command
CPU Vendor name: GenuineIntel <= Vendor string is good
CPU Brand: D:  l(R)  Core(TMD:   CPU       MD:  <= What..?
ok
```

Vendor string supposed to be:

```
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 540
```

But what I got is:

```
 D:  l(R)  Core(TMD:   CPU       MD:
```

C++ code:

```
            char vendorString[13] = { 0, };
            Dword eax, ebx, ecx, edx;
            ACpuid(0, &eax, &ebx, &ecx, &edx);
            *((Dword*)vendorString) = ebx;
            *((Dword*)vendorString + 1) = edx;
            *((Dword*)vendorString + 2) = ecx;
            Console::Output.Write(L"CPU vendor name: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
                Console::Output.Write((wchar_t)(vendorString[i]));
            }
            Console::Output.WriteLine();

            char brandString[48] = { 0, };
            ACpuid(0x80000002, &eax, &ebx, &ecx, &edx);
            *((Dword*)brandString) = eax;
            *((Dword*)brandString + 1) = ebx;
            *((Dword*)brandString + 2) = ecx;
            *((Dword*)brandString + 3) = edx;
            ACpuid(0x80000003, &eax, &ebx, &ecx, &edx);
            *((Dword*)brandString + 4) = eax;
            *((Dword*)brandString + 5) = ebx;
            *((Dword*)brandString + 6) = ecx;
            *((Dword*)brandString + 7) = edx;
            ACpuid(0x80000004, &eax, &ebx, &ecx, &edx);
            *((Dword*)brandString + 8) = eax;
            *((Dword*)brandString + 9) = ebx;
            *((Dword*)brandString + 10) = ecx;
            *((Dword*)brandString + 11) = edx;
            Console::Output.Write(L"CPU brand: ");
            for (int i = 0; i < 48; i++) {
                Console::Output.Write((wchar_t) brandString[i]);
            }
            Console::Output.WriteLine();
```

NOTE:

1. This program is UEFI application. No problem with permissions.
2. Console is an wrapper class for EFI console. Not C# stuff.
3. Dword = unsigned 32bit integer

Assembly code(MASM):

```
;Cpuid command
;ACpuid(Type, pEax, pEbx, pEcx, pEdx)
ACpuid Proc
    ;Type => Rcx
    ;pEax => Rdx
    ;pEbx => R8
    ;pEcx => R9
    ;pEdx => [ rbp + 48 ] ?
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    push rax
    push rsi

    mov rax, rcx
    cpuid
    mov [ rdx ], eax
    mov [ r8 ], ebx
    mov [ r9 ], ecx
    mov rsi, [ rbp + 48 ]
    mov [ rsi ], rdx

    pop rsi
    pop rax
    pop rbp
    ret
ACpuid Endp
```

Comment: Stupid question. Does your program has full permissions?

Comment: Do you mean C++ or C#?

Comment: @MichaelPetch C++. Console is a namespace for EFI console.(And Console::Output is console output) Not Console class in C#.

Comment: Ah okay, was just making sure

Comment: @Auriga This program is UEFI application.. I believe there is no problem with permissions.

Comment: Try using the `__cpuid` intrinsic instead of an assembly function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with Ross Ridge that you should use the compiler intrinsic [__cpuid](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hskdteyh.aspx). As for why your code likely doesn't work as is - there are some bugs that will cause problems.

---

[*CPUID*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPUID) destroys the contents of *RAX*, *RBX*, *RCX*, and *RDX* and yet you do this in your code:

```
cpuid
mov [ rdx ], eax
```

*RDX* has been destroyed by the time `mov [ rdx ], eax` is executed, rendering the pointer in *RDX* invalid. You'll need to move *RDX* to another register before using the `CPUID` instruction.

Per the [Windows 64-bit Calling Convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t169e9c.aspx) these are the volatile registers that need to be preserved by the **caller**:

> The registers RAX, RCX, RDX, R8, R9, R10, R11 are considered volatile and must be considered destroyed on function calls (unless otherwise safety-provable by analysis such as whole program optimization).

These are the non-volatile ones that need to be preserved by the **callee**:

> The registers RBX, RBP, RDI, RSI, RSP, R12, R13, R14, and R15 are considered nonvolatile and must be saved and restored by a function that uses them.

We can use *R10* (a volatile register) to store *RDX* temporarily. Rather than use *RSI* in the code we can reuse *R10* for updating the value at `pEdx`. We won't need to preserve *RSI* if we don't use it. *CPUID* does destroy *RBX*, and *RBX* is non-volatile, so we need to preserve it. *RAX* is volatile so we don't need to preserve it.

---

In your code you have this line:

```
mov [ rsi ], rdx
```

*RSI* is a memory address (`pEdx`) provided by the caller to store the value in *EDX*. The code you have would move the contents of the 8-byte register *RDX* to a memory location that was expecting a 4-byte *DWORD*. This could potentially trash data in the caller. This really should have been:

```
mov [ rsi ], edx
```

---

With all of the above in mind we could code the `ACpuid` routine this way:

```
option casemap:none
.code

;Cpuid command
;ACpuid(Type, pEax, pEbx, pEcx, pEdx)
ACpuid Proc
    ;Type => Rcx
    ;pEax => Rdx
    ;pEbx => R8
    ;pEcx => R9
    ;pEdx => [ rbp + 48 ] ?
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    push rbx         ; Preserve RBX (destroyed by CPUID)

    mov r10, rdx     ; Save RDX before CPUID
    mov rax, rcx
    cpuid
    mov [ r10 ], eax
    mov [ r8 ], ebx
    mov [ r9 ], ecx
    mov r10, [ rbp + 48 ]
    mov [ r10 ], edx ; Last parameter is pointer to 32-bit DWORD, 
                     ;  Move EDX to the memory location, not RDX

    pop rbx
    pop rbp
    ret
ACpuid Endp

end
```

Comment: I'd also suggest changing the function signature to just pass one pointer to a struct!  Simpler code on both ends that way.  (But still way more complicated than using a compiler builtin like `__cpuid()`).

Comment: @PeterCordes : I'm intentionally not changing the structure of his code. I was identifying the primary issues that would have been responsible for his code not functioning properly. The better solution is in the first line of my answer. Use the __cpuid compiler intrinsic and the assembler routine is unnecessary.